# Nice clothes for Hanukkah

Tags: halacha, chanuka, clothing

Is there a reason to wear special nice clothing on Hanukkah?

I would guess not as since there is no festive meal, it doesn't seem like it is a festive day.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kaf HaChaim http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14422&st=&pgnum=340 says that there are 3 levels of nicer clothing. The nicest ones are for Yom Tov, the next level is for Shabbos, and the lower level is for Chol HaMoed, Rosh Chodesh, Chanuka & Purim.

Answer (score 4):

[Darkei Chaim Veshalom](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8807&pgnum=313) writes that the Michas Elazar would wear his Shabbos clothing and Shtreimel from before he lit Chanuka candles until he went to sleep.

However, [Chabad](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/59.htm) custom is to wear normal(weekday) clothing even when lighting.